# How many devices can be connected to my home WiFi connection?

Tags: wireless-networking

We have 10 devices that require WiFi connection. Not all devices are connected at once but many times a day my devices (iPad and iPhone) get *disconnected*.

Sometimes just reconnecting works, other times the password needs to be reentered. On the other devices this also happens but not as often as on mine.

I was told that this may be because of the number of devices connected at once but not from a qualified source and I can not find my answer anywhere else.

Comment: This question is missing details necessary for us to help you. What router are you using? Are you using the stock firmware or a custom firmware? How is your router configured?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what is the device you are connecting to ? If it's your home router, provided by your ISP then no such low hard limits should be in effect (although that may be ISP related policy, cannot comment on that).

Generally speaking WiFi does not have a "cap" on # connections except when the medium it uses to send / receive data is saturated. In practice that means that, if you have a WiFi hotspot capable of 802.11N for instance running 5Ghz frequency theoretically you'd have 300Mbps throughput.

However, since the medium is shared ("air" / Frequency) you need to devide the #Bandwidth by the number of connected devices (since each will get their own share of the bandwidth).

Running 1 client would = 300Mbps (theoretical) for that client.
Running 2 clients would = 150Mbps (theoretical) for each client

With specific regards to your issue, I would look elsewhere.

For instance, run a WiFi analyzer (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/wifi-analyzer/9nblggh33n0n)

and see if your WiFi is sharing the Frequency AND Channel with a neighbour who also has WiFi on for instance.

If you are both, for instance on 5 Ghz and your channels are near each other (you on 2, him on 3) and you see a free channel, try and switching your router to use the channel that is free. That could improve both your connectivity as well as throughput.

Hope this helps you out a bit, at least be able to identify / troubleshoot some basic things (By using the WiFi analyser).

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You will be limited by **CSMA/CA** nature, not by IP addresses. The rule of thumb is 25 clients per access point.

Comment: Links to documentation to support your answer would be nice.

Comment: Like this....http://serverfault.com/questions/192905/whats-the-maximum-number-of-wifi-connections-for-a-single-wifi-router

Answer (score 0):

You can, theoretically, connect 254 devices to a single Wi-Fi router/access point (you have to substract the gateway address and the broadcast address). But that doesn’t mean you should.

By the way, you should read the specs of the Access Point you are using. Not all AP support the same number of devices against it

Comment: That answers how many devices can be used in a /24 network, most network equipment can be configured to use  another prefix length than /24, allowing for more IP's. The real restriction is the quality of the router, not the availibility of IP addresses.

Comment: That's why i said theoretically. It is needed to check the limit of devices supported by the AP and a audit a proper channel in the wireless network not too busy

Comment: Changing the netmask from /24 to something bigger increases this, so this isn't even a limit, it's just the default for most home routers.

Comment: And following your logic the answer should be 253, since you didn't count the network address.